# jquery selector to get all anchor elements within a given div, no matter how deeply they are nested?

Tags: javascript, jquery

suppose some markup such as:

```
<div id="header">
   <div id="nest-one>
      <a href="#">one</a>
      <div id="nest-two">
         <a href="#">two</a>
         <a href="#">three</a>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I want to tie a single click handler to all of the a tags.

I tried the following, but didn;t seem to work.  I know I'm missing something stupid easy, just not sure what it is.

```
$('#header a').click(function(){alert('on click')});
```

Comment: Is that line of JavaScript in the document ready, or at least after the HTML in the source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On this line:

```
<div id="nest-one>
```

You've missed the closing double-quote on the id.

Aside from that, make sure any JavaScript referencing HTML elements is in the document ready function and/or after those elements in the source.

Comment: markup was just a sample, I think its the document ready pice that I was missing.  gonna try it out and assuming it works, accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CuDMp/1)

---

#### EDIT

per BoltClock's point:

This works actually

```
$('#header a').click(function(){alert('on click')});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $.live or $.delgate, this will also bind to any future elements added dynamically to the DOM.

example:

```
$("#header").delegate("a", "click", function() {
  console.log("%o clicked", this ); // log object in firebug
});
```

Comment: don't think that will make much of a difference